# Hibernate Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, orm

Can anyone suggest me a good eclipse plug-in for Hibernate. The plug in should take care of generation of POJO classes, hbm mapping files. Also provide a nice interface to execute HQL queries. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Regards,
Nitin Ware

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Hibernate guys provides such a plugin for Eclipse part of the [Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html). It supports **Reverse Engineering** from an existing database to generate entities and mapping files and offers an **HQL Editor** and a **Criteria Editor**. From the official website:

> **Console:** The Hibernate Console perspective allows you to configure
>   database connections, provides
>   visualization of classes and their
>   relationships and allows you to
>   execute HQL queries interactively
>   against your database and browse the
>   query results.
>
> [image]
>
> **Reverse Engineering:** The most powerful feature of Hibernate Tools is
>   a database reverse engineering tool
>   that can generate domain model classes
>   and Hibernate mapping files, annotated
>   EJB3 entity beans, HTML documentation
>   or even an entire JBoss Seam
>   application in seconds!

Answer (score 4):

I think the most popular is http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/hibernate-tools

Comment: This appears to be the same plugin as in Pascal's answer.

Comment: @MatrixFrog or you could say Pascal's answer is the same plugin since Jano pointed it out first. Either way they both mentioned the best answer.